# Fresh IMX6 IC booting

Tags: imx31

I have new custom development board ready for IMX6 which is similar design of Sabre board.
But, I would like to know whether the new IC ( MCIMX6Q5EY10AD ) is having u-boot or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U-boot is not on the processor. You need to build it and copy to the SD CARD. Have a look at this post for detailed instructions.

https://community.freescale.com/docs/DOC-95015